# Verify divisibility rules using bitwise operations

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

How can I verify if a number `n` is divisible by `x` using bitwise operations?

I find lot of related links on this but I don't clearly understand them as they were not in Python. For example, what if I want to verify if `81` is divisible by `3`, `9` or `4`?

I want to use bitwise operations and I want to understand how to implement this using Python.

Comment: *Why* do you want to implement it with bitwise operation?

Comment: Why not just `81 % 3 == 0`?

Comment: There is a requirement that I should implement this using bitwise operations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bitwise operation as their name let guess operate on binary representation of numbers. That means that they will be highly efficient to test divisibility by a power or 2, but hardly usable for any other case.

Examples:

- n divisible by 2 : `n & 1 == 0`
- n divisible by 4 : `n & 3 == 0`
- n divisible by 8 : `n & 7 == 0`

There are other divisibility rules that could be used: you could adapt the [casting out 9 or 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) to test divisibility by 15 or 17 (base 16 uses to nibbles per byte), but as one single integer division is often faster than making many simpler operations (accumulator directly processes numbers of 32 or 64 bits) they are seldom used...

If your requirement is to test divisibility by 3 and 9, you could adapt *casting out 9* for 3 = 4 - 1, and *11* for 9 =8+1. `81 = 0b1010001`

- 3: sum of *2 bit digits* must be divisible by 3 - starting with little weights : 01+00+01+01=0b11 (=3): divisible
- 9: sum of odd *3 bit digits* minus sum of even ones must be divisible by 9=0b1001 - odd: 001+001=010, even: 010 - difference is 0: divisible

You can code this easily with shifts (`>>`) and binary `&`

Comment: I had to use bitwise to test divisibility of n by 3  and 9 too. Is there any link that will help me?

Comment: @SupreethMeka @SergeBallesta - for bigint inputs with thousands or even millions worth of digits, if either the original decimal, a base 4 str, or a hex string is readily available (w/o conversion work), it's waaaay faster doing `mod 3` via a high-speed `regex` engine - using the exact same function, scrub out all `[0369CFILORUXcfx]+`, get the string length at this point of time and double it (`2 * a`), then high speed cast out all `[258BEHKNQTWZbe]+`….

Comment: …. and finally, return `mod 3` once you've subtract the left over string length, i.e. `( 2 * a - b ) % 3`. This way you can do `mod 3` on all bases from 4 to 34 congruent to `1 (mod 3)`. The larger the input, the better it is, and no limitation to scalability of it, simply because no math was actually performed to perform unnecessary 10-to-2 base conversion. But it's only faster when your input is at least 256-bits  or so. below that, the standard approach is likely faster. packed bytes could also use the same approach cuz 256 has the same base congruence.

Comment: Pure binary strings and octal strings need to be grouped to use this approach cuz even though they themselves are the same congruence mod 3, they don't share that congruence with decimal hex and the byte. If it's any solace, any base that is a Mersenne Prime itself would also work with this approach. It's a similar idea to casting out 9's, but `regex` is far more agile here because it can handle all of those bases without even performing any base conversions at all - 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34…256… etc.